# My state changes, but does not add class when useEffect, when I scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to change the background of a JSX element when the page goes down by 320 px, all with useEffect and useState. So far I managed to change the state, but does not add background class of another color.

> I am using NODE 8.9.3, NPM 5.5.1 and REACT JS 16.9.0

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useScrollYPosition } from 'react-use-scroll-position'

import { Container } from '../../styles/Container'
import { ContainerCustom, HeaderComp } from './styles'

import Logo from './Logo'
import Menu from './Menu'
import Icons from './Icons'

const ContainerBox = () => {
  return (
    <ContainerCustom fluid>
      <Container>
        <HeaderComp>
          <Logo />
          <Menu />
          <Icons />
        </HeaderComp>
      </Container>
    </ContainerCustom>
  )
}

const Header = () => {
  const [back, setBack] = useState(0)

  const handleBackState = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY
    if (scrollY > 320) {
      setBack(1)
      console.log(`Estado: ${back}`)
    } else {
      setBack(0)
      console.log(`Estado após remover: ${back}`)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleBackState)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleBackState)
    }
  }, [handleBackState])
  return <ContainerBox className={back === 1 ? 'removeGradients' : ''} />
}
```

> On console has the output State: 0, and after 320, State after remove:
>   1

Comment: You provided `scrollY` as a dependency to `useEffect` but this is only defined inside the handler not in the scope you call `useEffect`. Does that code even work? The correct dependency would be `handleBackState` which should be wrapped in `useCallback`. You could even inline it and let `useEffect` have no dependency at all.

Comment: I changed the scrollY for handleBackState in useEffect dependency ... continued working state but does not update the class.

Comment: Are you aware that `scrollY` is not defined in that scope unless you omitted some code? You can't use it there because it it only defined inside of the handler. The correct dependency would be `handleBackState` if anything. But you can just inline the handler inside of your `useEffect`.

Comment: Is `ContainerBox` even accepting the `className` property and forwarding it to the DOM element?

Comment: The className property is not changing or mutating.

Comment: I doubt that. It does work as expected in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shape-jkn6g) with exactly your code. Are you sure that `ContainerBox` even uses that `className` property? Please post the code of `ContainerBox`.

Comment: Please edit your question rather then posting it as a comment. Your `ContainerBox` doesn't do anything with `className`.

Comment: Okay thank you. Have you also read my comments? As my [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shape-jkn6g) shows, the code works as expected and className updates correctly BUT `ContainerBox` does nothing with it. What is the expected behaviour? If you want the class name to be applied to a DOM element you have to pass it down all the way to that element.

Comment: Thank you so much so far ... I have read all the comments and this is exactly what I expect. That the class is added to the DOM element, but I do not know how to do it from this point I am.

Comment: Well you have to further pass the prop `className` down to the component that actutally renders the DOM element you want to style. `ContainerBox` itself is not a DOM element. It has to be a `div` or something like that. Maybe `ContainerCustom` renders it? You have to pass `className` further down to the actual `div`.

Comment: thank you very much. I was able to change the classes .. the error was exactly what commented ... the ContainerBox was not a DOM element, so I could not change the class ... I applied all the logic in the Container element and finally it worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every component also has a representation in the DOM. You need to apply the `className` to a component that actually has a corresponding DOM element to have your styles take any effect:

```
// className will not affect the DOM as this component does not render a DOM element
const WrappingComponent = ({className}) => (
    <WrappedComponent className={className} />
);

// this className will be applied to the div in the DOM
const WrappedComponent = ({className}) => (
    <div className={className}>Content here</div>
);
```